# Undefined function eval() - PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to use the eval() function like that :

```
$foo = 'eval';
$bar = 'echo 1;';
$foo($bar);
```

But i'm getting an error : Fatal error: Call to undefined function eval()

That's strange because the following code is working

```
$foo = 'base64_encode';
$bar = 'foobar';
echo $foo($bar);
```

Can anyone help about it ?

Comment: It's because it's evil !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [`eval` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php):

> **Note:** Because this is a language construct and not a function, it cannot be called using [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php).

Following the link in the note you will also find:

> Variable functions won't work with language constructs such as `echo`, `print`, `unset()`, `isset()`, `empty()`, `include`, `require` and the like. Utilize wrapper functions to make use of any of these constructs as variable functions.

Comment: @ficuscr There can be extremely practical and useful uses for `eval`. The problem is that it is abused.

Comment: Grudgingly agree... Though  they are few and far between.  And not in this way - pretty sure the variable function isn't for readability.  Seen more valid use cases for `goto`...